# how to determine the the execution time, CPU and memory utilization of a shell script(test.sh)?

Tags: linux, shell, freebsd, csh

I need to know the complete execution time, CPU and memory utilization of a shell script that I have written. I want to execute the commands that outputs the CPU and memory utilization from the same script. I am more interested in real time CPU utilization rather than average time CPU utilization when the script finishes its execution.Is this feasible? OS - FreeBSD and linux

Please help.

Comment: You can get the execution time with the `time` util. Try `time sh test.sh`.

Comment: How frequently do you need to see the instantaneous cpu utilization? If you just need to know it on demand, typing Control-T (on freebsd)  may be enough.

Comment: Hi Mark, 
Thanks for your reply, I need to know the exact cpu utilization when the script finishes its execution.So if the script runs for say 10 seconds then what the CPU % it took during 10 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question is you want to know how much CPU is been utilized by your script. Then just after running your script capture the process id of that script/processes and use 
ps -p  -o %cpu,%mem command  to see the CPU utilization

Comment: Thanks for your reply Anupam, my script hardly runs for 20-25 seconds, I could not get the process id using "top", I even tried assigning the process name to my script but couln't do so. Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: Ohk. Just add ps -ef| grep script name in your file at second line. This will capture the process id and add this command with ps -p pid -o %cpu,%mem.  Then use & at the end of script to make it run in back end.